# Repair Faux Wood Grain on Cabinetry

Tags: cabinets

I had a question about repairing the boards and side boards of kitchen cabinetry. I am not actually wanting to fix the actual cabinets, but the sides of the cabinets are made with some type of wood and then it looks like they pressed with a faux wood grain veneer or contact paper. On  another cabinet (not shown), the faux wood grain paper/veneer or whatever you want to call it, has started to chip off. I think it’s either cause of old-age, humidity, moisture, etc. Since it’s just a faux wood grain finish on top of a cheap wood, what is the best way to repair it? I thought of a few options which range from a cover up to a complete replacement:
-try to match a wood filler crayon or marker and just cover up the missing portions. This would be a quick fix.
-find a matching tape or contact paper and just cover up the relevant portions
-find a paint that would cover up the portions
-find a contact paper roll or veneer finish and completely cut the paper and paste it onto the side of the cabinetry.

I really want to stay away from a replacement and would rather just find a quick fix or cover up. From your experience and insight, what do you think would be the best? What color do you think would match these faux grains?
[picture of wood grain on side of cabinet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImIra.jpg)

[image: edit: here is the piece I actually am dealing with. I would like to repair the worn out portion above the trim]

Comment: Do you think this will do the trick? Good match? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002TDVPCI/ref=asc_df_B002TDVPCI5215653/?tag=hyprod-20&creative=394997&creativeASIN=B002TDVPCI&linkCode=df0&hvadid=194794599051&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14028291073698074904&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061285&hvtargid=pla-311457384144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repairing this type of material is difficult, although I have seen it done.  It is an art project of matching paint colors and drawing in the wood grain.  I doubt it will hold up though.  Covering it up is your best option and there are several ways to do it.

1 - I think your best bet is to find a cabinet refacing supplier.  There are many on the internet and you should be able to find an end skin.  This is either a thin sheet of plywood or veneer and many are self adhesive. In cabinet refacing, they cover the outside surfaces of a cabinet and replace the doors so they have a lot of color and wood options.

2 - You can buy what is essentially wood grain contact paper and cover it up.  Be sure that surface is as clean as possible before applying the new contact paper.

3 - I see a small strip of wood at the bottom.  I would have to see what the whole cabinet looks like, but you may be able to take that off and replace it with a wider strip of wood if the damage is confined to the lower part of the cabinet as it appears in this picture.

4 - You can go the a local wood store and buy veneer or thin plywood and stain it to match.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, WoodAirGrille. I was thinking about the below contact paper, looks like a match to either cover the whole side or just the portion. What do you think?https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002TDVPCI/ref=asc_df_B002TDVPCI5215653/?tag=hyprod-20&creative=394997&creativeASIN=B002TDVPCI&linkCode=df0&hvadid=194794599051&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14028291073698074904&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061285&hvtargid=pla-311457384144

Comment: You are going to be a better judge of the match than I am because you have the piece to compare with.  I would suggest covering the whole side corner to corner though.